# How to get object data with Jetstream and Livewire

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream

I have similar issue with [Laravel 8 Jetstream || Undefined variable: _instance (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\veye-website\resources\views\vendor\jetstream\components\modal.blade.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64438902/laravel-8-jetstream-undefined-variable-instance-view-c-xampp-htdocs-veye) From here I understand that Livewire methods work in Livewire components.

However, how do I get data using Jetstream components?

My working (I'm creating another users page, as example) :

1. create users.blade.php under resource/views/vendor/jetstream/components containing the following snippet

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ $user->name }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ $user->email }}
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

2. create app\Http\Livewire\userlist.php with a simple code

```
public function render()
    {
        $users = User::all();
        return view('user', compact("users"));
    }
```

I know there is something wrong with (2) putting it under Livewire. But how else can it be done, without moving users.blade.php to views\livewire component. I'm also using users.blade.php so that it will be possible to call `<x-jet-users>`.

Answer (score 0):

in your user.blade.php, include the livewire component using the directive as

```
@livewire('user-component-from-livewire')
```

into the livewire component's blade add the code you are handling above

```
// at livewire/user-component-from-livewire.blade.php
<div>
@foreach($users as $user)
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ $user->name }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ $user->email }}
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
</div>

// in component
public function render()
{
   return view('user-component-from-livewire', ['users' => User::all()]);
}
```

so, always you render the jetstream component, it´s going to call to livewire related at nested

Comment: now having error bootstrap/cache directory must be present and writable. need to look into this